# Trouble spliting a column into more columns on Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, split, rdd, pyspark

I'm having trouble spliting a dataframe's column into more columns in PySpark:

I have a list of lists and I want to transform it into a dataframe, each value in one column.

What I have tried:

I created a dataframe from this list:

```
[['COL-4560', 'COL-9655', 'NWG-0610', 'D81-3754'],
 ['DLL-7760', 'NAT-9885', 'PED-0550', 'MAR-0004', 'LLL-5554']]
```

Using this code:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
R = Row('col1', 'col2')

# use enumerate to add the ID column
df_from_list = spark.createDataFrame([R(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(recs_list)])
```

The result I got is:

```
+----+--------------------+
|col1|                col2|
+----+--------------------+
|   0|[COL-4560, COL-96...|
|   1|[DLL-7760, NAT-98...|
+----+--------------------+
```

I want to separate the values by comma into columns, so I tried:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df_from_list.select('col1', F.split('col2', ', ').alias('col2'))

# If you don't know the number of columns:
df_sizes = df2.select(F.size('col2').alias('col2'))
df_max = df_sizes.agg(F.max('col2'))
nb_columns = df_max.collect()[0][0]

df_result = df2.select('col1', *[df2['col2'][i] for i in range(nb_columns)])
df_result.show()
```

But I get an error on this line `df2 = df_from_list.select('col1', F.split('col2', ', ').alias('col2'))`:

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'split(`col2`, ', ', -1)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`col2`' is of array<string> type.;;
```

My ideal final output would be like this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  SKU     |  REC_01  | REC_02   | REC_03   | REC_04   |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| COL-4560 | COL-9655 | NWG-0610 | D81-3754 | null     |
| DLL-7760 | NAT-9885 | PED-0550 | MAR-0004 | LLL-5554 |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Some rows may have four values, but some my have more or less, I don't know the exact number of columns the final dataframe will have.

Does anyone have any idea of what is happening? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe `df_from_list` **`col2`** column is already **`array`** type, so **no need to split** (as **split** works with **stringtype** here we have **arraytype**).

Here are the steps that will work for you.

```
recs_list=[['COL-4560', 'COL-9655', 'NWG-0610', 'D81-3754'],
 ['DLL-7760', 'NAT-9885', 'PED-0550', 'MAR-0004', 'LLL-5554']]

from pyspark.sql import Row
R = Row('col1', 'col2')

# use enumerate to add the ID column
df_from_list = spark.createDataFrame([R(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(recs_list)])

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df_from_list

# If you don't know the number of columns:
df_sizes = df2.select(F.size('col2').alias('col2'))
df_max = df_sizes.agg(F.max('col2'))
nb_columns = df_max.collect()[0][0]

cols=['SKU','REC_01','REC_02','REC_03','REC_04']
df_result = df2.select(*[df2['col2'][i] for i in range(nb_columns)]).toDF(*cols)
df_result.show()
#+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
#|     SKU|  REC_01|  REC_02|  REC_03|  REC_04|
#+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
#|COL-4560|COL-9655|NWG-0610|D81-3754|    null|
#|DLL-7760|NAT-9885|PED-0550|MAR-0004|LLL-5554|
#+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```